# Is there something to auto-include files other than classes in PHP?

Tags: php

The magic __autoload function works for classes only, right? How about other files like templates? I'd love to see a solution where I don't have to care at all about the big problem "where's the file? what's the path? when do I have to include it?". Would be a big time saver.

Performance? Well... in this case I'd prefer faster development over performance, because...hey..lets face it, 99,99% of our websites we make are rarely visited anyways. And when the day comes where we get a million visitors, we're probably a big, Inc. and pay 10 devs to improve it.

Well, at least for my framework.

Comment: If your template was a class, then it would work with `__autoload`, too. =)

Comment: doesnt make much sense to make a template a class ;) rofl... I have ViewController's, Views, and Views use Templates. These are just plain "html" files with .php at the end for PHP as the templating language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look [set_include_path()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php). It allows you to set a list of a directories in which PHP will look when you try to include a file. So if you have all your templates in one dir, say `templates/`, you can just:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'templates');
//...
include 'mytemplate.php';
```

And PHP will find the right file. This still requires an include(), but it helps. Besides, being explicit about which files you include is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can go one better.

look in the php.ini file for auto_prepend_file and auto_append_file.

auto_prepend_file   NULL    PHP_INI_PERDIR      PHP_INI_ALL in PHP <= 4.2.3.
auto_append_file    NULL    PHP_INI_PERDIR          PHP_INI_ALL in PHP <= 4.2.3.

auto_prepend_file  string

```
Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed before the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require() function, so include_path is used.

The special value none disables auto-prepending.
```

auto_append_file string

```
Specifies the name of a file that is automatically parsed after the main file. The file is included as if it was called with the require() function, so include_path is used.

The special value none disables auto-appending.

    Note: If the script is terminated with exit(), auto-append will not occur.
```