# Basic PHP require/directory structure

Tags: php

Current structure:

```
htdocs
  mums
    demo.php
    login.php
    mums
      classes
        mums.class.php
      includes
        global.inc.php
        config.inc.php
```

I want to keep mysql database info and the location of the folder containing the mums folder (the internal one) in config.inc.php. Example:

```
// CONFIG
$mumsConfig['dbName'] = 'mums';
$mumsConfig['dbUser'] = 'root';
$mumsConfig['dbPass'] = 'pass';
$mumsConfig['dbHost'] = 'localhost';
$mumsConfig['folder'] = 'mums';
// END CONFIG
```

I'd like to include the config file in any class.php file that needs it and also in the global.inc.php file for every page that needs it. The problem is I'm storing the location of the library ($mumsConfig['folder']) in the config file, so I can't include the config.inc.php file until I know that, which is in the file itself.....

I'm really at a loss on how to set up a very simple config file. FYI this is all staying on LAN so no need to worry about security.

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986146/is-there-something-to-auto-include-files-other-than-classes-in-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986146/is-there-something-to-auto-include-files-other-than-classes-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both include files are in the same directory i.e under includes. You can just do `require('config.inc.php')` in global.inc.php

Comment: When I include global.inc.php in another file, doesn't that mess up the directory the script runs in?

Comment: It shouldn't. Are you experiencing any problems ? I just did a small test and it's not a problem for me.

Comment: So you're doing a `require('global.inc.php')` in another file ?

Comment: yeah. I have a demo.php file in the htdocs/mums folder, and it includes global.inc.php from the htdocs/mums/mums/includes folder, and the global.inc.php file includes config.inc.php which is also in the includes folder

Comment: And actually, I wasn't having a problem just using    require('config.inc.php') in the global.inc.php, my problem now is a bit strange. When I figure out how to explain it, I'll let you know...

Comment: Here's what I've got now: I've got two pages I'm using to test this. One is htdocs/mums/demo.php, and the other is htdocs/mums/test/test.php. Each file includes global.inc.php. In global.inc.php, it includes config.inc.php. Then it uses a variable inside config.inc.php to set a variable called $root. If I echo $root, I see it on both pages, so I know everything up to that is working. The next include is /htdocs/mums/mums/classes/mums.class.php...

Comment: ...It has a __construct class that takes the $root variable from global.inc.php and uses it to include config.inc.php    require($root.'mums/includes/config.inc.php'); Here's the issue: In demo.php, everything loads fine, but in test/test.php, I get an error that $root is undefined in mums.class.php...Totally lost here